# Why is this not inserting a document into my MongoDB collection?

Tags: javascript, mongodb, meteor

I've got this code to try to insert a document (record) into a MongoDB collection (table):

```
TimeAndSpace = new Mongo.Collection('timeAndSpace');

if (Meteor.isClient) {
    Template.addTimeSpaceForm.events({
        'submit form': function() {
            event.PreventDefault();
            var city = "Fort Bragg";
            var state = "California";
            var yearin = 1958;
            var yearout = 1959;
            // var city = event.target.city.value;
            // var state = event.target.state.value;
            // var yearin = event.target.yearin.value;
            // var yearout = event.target.yearout.value;
            Meteor.call('insertLocationData', city, state, yearin, yearout);
        }
    });

}

if (Meteor.isServer) {
  Meteor.startup(function () {
    // code to run on server at startup
  });
}

Meteor.methods({
    'insertLocationData': function(city, state, yearin, yearout) {
        console.log('attempting to insert a record');
        TimeAndSpace.insert({
            ts_city: city,
            ts_state: state,
            ts_yearin: yearin,
            ts_yearout: yearout
        });
    }
});
```

It doesn't work. Entering the following in the Chrome Dev Tools (F12) console:

```
TimeAndSpace.find().fetch()
```

...returns "[]" - obviously indicating the collection has no documents.

The only thing the console shows me after hitting the "Add Place Lived" submit button is:

```
XHR finished loading: GET "http://localhost:3000/sockjs/info?cb=jmghsx3ec6".
```

In case you want/need to know, here is the HTML:

```
<head>
  <title>timeandspace</title>
</head>

<body>
  <h1>A List of the Places I Have Lived</h1>
  {{> addTimeSpaceForm}}
</body>

<template name="addTimeSpaceForm">
<form>
    <label for="city">City</label>
    <input type="text" name="city" id="city">
    <br/>
    <label for="state">State</label>
    <input type="text" name="state" id="state">
    <br/>
    <label for="yearin">Year Arrived</label>
    <input type="text" name="yearin" id="yearin">
    <br/>
    <label for="yearout">Year Departed</label>
    <input type="text" name="yearout" id="yearout">
    <br/>
    <input type="submit" name="insertdocument" id="insertdocument" value="Add Place Lived">
</form>
</template>
```

What am I missing or missing fire on?

Comment: is `event.PreventDefault();` a typo or do you really have it with a capital P in your code? Does the event handler execute (did you put a `console.log` in there to check)? Also is event defined? in the code you show it is not.

Comment: I switched the `P` to a lowercase `p` in `event.PreventDefault()`. Then I used `meteor mongo` to inspect the collections and it inserted properly.

Comment: @Sgnl: Where is meteor mongo available? I tried it in Chrome Dev Tools, and got nothing (well, I got "Uncaught syntax error: Unexpected identifier").

Comment: It's available on the machine that is running the meteor server,

Comment: @Sgnl: All of this is running locally on one machine - my home laptop. But "meteor mongo" seems to be command-non-grata everywhere I've tried it. Are you sure I don't need to install something else first?

Comment: My version of meteor is `Meteor 1.1.0.2` and I'm on OSX. I'm fairly sure it should come with Meteor out of the box.

Comment: I'm using 1.1.0.3, on Windows 8.1

Comment: Yeah I just checked, it 'should' be available regardless of OS.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because you make some small typo and missing mistakes. For instance you are missing event in your function. And then you try PreventDefault instead of the correct preventDefault. Also Methods should be placed on server side only. I also took the liberty to make it functional with your form already. Here is the code and a link to a functional meteor pad.

```
TimeAndSpace = new Mongo.Collection('timeAndSpace');

if (Meteor.isClient){
    Template.addTimeSpaceForm.events({
        'submit form': function(event){
            event.preventDefault();
            var city = event.target.city.value;
            var state = event.target.state.value;
            var yearin = event.target.yearin.value;
            var yearout = event.target.yearout.value;

            Meteor.call('insertLocationData', city, state, yearin, yearout);
            console.log(TimeAndSpace.find().fetch());
        }
    });
}

if (Meteor.isServer){
  Meteor.methods({
      'insertLocationData': function(city, state, yearin, yearout){
          console.log('attempting to insert a record');
          TimeAndSpace.insert({
              ts_city: city,
              ts_state: state,
              ts_yearin: yearin,
              ts_yearout: yearout
          });

          console.log(TimeAndSpace.find().fetch());
      }
  });
}
```

http://meteorpad.com/pad/qgEmW5hv8N4yCaH6s/Why%20is%20this%20not%20inserting%20a%20document%20into%20my%20MongoDB%20collection?